# How to replace multiple instances of curly braces with preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

For fun and as a learning experience I'm trying to create my own URL routing library.

How do I replace an url like this:

```
/board/{forum}/{topic}
```

with this:

```
/board/(.*)/(.*)
```

I'm doing:

```
preg_replace("#\{.*\}#", '(.*)' ,'/board/{forum}/{topic}', -1);
```

But getting:

```
/board/(.*)
```

Comment: `preg_replace("#\{.*?\}#", '(.*)' ,'/board/{forum}/{topic}');`

Comment: Why an extra `)` at the last?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I think OP just don't show us all the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a `?` in your regex so it is not greedy like this:

```
#\{.*?\}#
   //^ See here
```